# Same value must exist at least 3 times in a Matrix

Tags: matlab

The matrix <1x500> consists of different values, now I want to check if any of the values in the matrix occurs at least 3 times or more.

```
if (val occurs  3 times or more)
   do
```

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option from @KiW answer for when you need to know all the values that do appear at least 3 times is:

```
uniqA=unique(A);
counts=histcounts(A,[uniqA inf]);
vals_that_are_bigger=uniqA(counts>=3);
```

To check if any of them are bigger than 3, just

```
if any(counts>=3)
```

Comment: hum, but I think this worked in my computer as it is.... I think you are right though, @LuisMendo . If you are confident it is, please edit it, else I will try tomorrow and edit it myself

Answer (score 1):

```
if numel(find(matrix)==val)>3
whatever you want to do
end
```

Comment: I would probably just do `sum(matrix(:) == val)`

Comment: yep that is more elegant!

Comment: Or maybe even `nnz(matrix(:) == val)` is faster.

Comment: Your first suggestion is the fastest ;) have a look at the edit

Comment: You should really use `timeit` to benchmark as a single `tic`/`toc` doesn't really do a good job of estimating execution time